# Is this formula from Wolfram wrong?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I tried to calculate the length of the side $a'$ of the contact triangle of $\Delta ABC$ (the side corresponding the the side $BC$), and I found $(-a+b+c)\sin \frac {A}2$
(if we denote the incenter by $I$, the ends of $a'$ by $E$ and $F$, and $M$ the midpoint of $EF$, we have $a'=EF=2FM=2\cdot AF\cdot \frac{FM}{AF}=2\cdot (s-a)\cdot \sin \angle FAM=(-a+b=c)\sin\frac{A}2$).

But [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContactTriangle.html) say this is $(-a+b+c)\cos \frac{A}2$. Am I wrong, or Wolfram is?

Comment: Please share your working on this problem. If you have made a mistake, this will allow us to point out where you error arises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula given by Wolfram is indeed wrong. Here is a counterexample: if the triangle is equilateral with sidelengths $a=b=c=1$ (with a contact triangle with sidelengths $a'=b'=c'=1/2$), using their formula gives

$$a'=(1+1-1)\cos(\pi/6)=\sqrt{3}/2$$

instead of $a'=1/2$.

Your proof is correct ; another one is given [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/def-is-the-triangle-formed-by-joining-the-points-of-contact-of-the-incircle-with/).